Pull request comment parameters for Jenkins build
I have a system that builds for multiple different devices in a parallel pipeline. As we have added more devices it is maxing out the resources and we've had to split the build into multiple pipelines. Now it takes far too long to build all. Is there a way to add a checkbox (or similar) to my github pull request to specify which devices to build. I would want it to default to building all, but if I check only a few then this would affect which devices build. Currently I manually change the Jenkinsfile to specify which ones to build, but it would be much more ideal to not have to edit the code each time we test a change.
I've looked into choice parameters, but that is done from Jenkins. I have it set up to where Jenkins automatically builds when a pull request is created. So that would require extra work to go into Jenkins then select. When creating the pull request I want to choose which devices it builds.Then when Jenkins auto starts the build it will only be the devices that I selected.

If this is a PR build, you can consider doing something like this:

Add a comment to the PR that specifies devices to build
When Jenkins starts the build, pull information about the comments in that PR using the API of whatever Git host you are using
Have conditional stages in your Jenkins build that build depending on the devices mentioned in the comment

Another way to do this is to allow remote execution of the Jenkins job, then call the remote endpoint with parameters (build_device_1=true, build_device_2=false, etc...). However I think the first option is the most straightforward way to do it...
